# split the latitude and longitude of the googleplacepicker, place.getLatLng()

Tags: java, android, google-places-api

How do I split the coordinates given by the `place.getLatLng()` function of `googleplacepicker` into double values of latitude and longitude separately stored .

Example of the output of `place.getLatLng()` is "lat/lng: (12.8614515,77.6647081)"

And how do I get lat= 12.8614515 and lng = 77.6647081

Answer (score 1):

I guess that is the output you get when you print place.getLatLng(). `getLanLng()` returns an object that has two variables `latitude` and `longitude` using which you can get the individual values.

Comment: no.
you get "lat/lng: (12.8614515,77.6647081)" as the output. And i want to split it seperately

Comment: It [does return](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/places/Place.html#getLatLng()) a [LatLng object](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/model/LatLng) from which you can read the [public 'latitude' and 'longitude' fields](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/model/LatLng.html#latitude). The "lat/lng: (12.8614515,77.6647081)" printout comes from its `toString()` method.

Answer (score 0):

- to get latitude, use `place.getLatLng().latitude`
- to get longitude use `place.getLatLng().longitude`

So the code for a `TextView` would be:

```java
textView.setText("Lat = " + place.getLatLng().latitude +
                 " Lng = " + place.getLatLng().longitude)
```